# jqplot - superscript in axis label

Tags: jqplot, superscript, axis-labels

As the title says how do I add superscript fonts to the axis labels in a jqplot graph?

I tried using Javascript sup() function and also actual html tags  for the titles of the axes but to no vain.

Basically I need to display units like m<sup>3</sup> etc. Do I have to tinker with the AxisLabelRenderer or is there any obvious workaround I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use unicode characters for do that;

1. "Superscript two"(\u00B2) (2)
2. "Superscript three" (\u00B3) (³)
3. "Superscript one" (\00B9) (¹)

try this:

```
      xaxis: {
      label: "Units m\u00B3"
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer, with HTML entities, which also works in jqPlot:

1. `&sup1;` (¹)
2. `&sup2;` (²)
3. `&sup3;` (³)

For example (m²):

```
  xaxis: {
    label: "m&sup2;"
  },
```