# Use superscript in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to use superscript in d3? I have the following code:

```
var counter = 2;
textNode.text("Event" + counter);// want counter to be the superscript
```

Should I use:

```
textNode.style(args);
```

to add superscripts?

Comment: What is superscript? Like text inside <sup> tags?

Comment: `var supNode = document.createElement('sup')`

Comment: @jsalonen Yes. Like text will be displayed in smaller font size in right upper corner.

Comment: @vittore Could you explain to me more in detail how will **var supNode = document.createElement('sup')** work? Where should supNode be inserted?

Comment: @Gao see here for a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723090/jqplot-superscript-in-axis-label

Answer (score 0):

Use select to get tag and use text to set text

```
d3.select('sup').text("Event" + counter)
```

Or if you need to create it

```
d3.select('body').append('sup').text("Event" + counter)
```